# How To save A JSON string to One Field Of Sqlite in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json, sqlite

Hi I have Some data in JSON format like below:

```
`contentJson=`[{"key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3","key4":"Value4","key5":"Value5","key6":"Value6","key7":"Value7", "key8":"Value8"},{"key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3","key4":"Value4","key5":"Value5","key6":"Value6","key7":"Value7", "key8":"Value8"}]
```

How can I save all Data to one Field in Sqlite Database ?

My code is

```
 NSString *statement = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mydatabase(contentJson,ID) VALUES(\"%@\",%d)",contentJson,ID];
```

But its not inserting anything.If i m inserting manually Through SQlitemanager then i  m getting Error such as error at "Key1 ......

I would highly appreciate it if someone could help me out by showing me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interporlated string would look like this :

```
INSERT INTO mydatabase(contentJson,ID) VALUES(
"[{"key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3","key4":"Value4",
"key5":"Value5","key6":"Value6","key7":"Value7", "key8":"Value8"},
{"key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3","key4":"Value4",
"key5":"Value5","key6":"Value6","key7":"Value7", "key8":"Value8"}]",
ID);
```

You need to exacpe the " in the string because it is confusing your rdbms.

Maybe try

```
NSString *statement = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mydatabase(contentJson,ID) VALUES('%@',%d)",contentJson,ID];
```

The true solution however would be to use Prepared Statements instead of SQL String in an appliaction. This is not an issue when you use prepared statements.

Comment: Your method normally work but what about you have string like this: **"Value's 48"** ?

Comment: Then you use a backspace replace for the `'` ... `"Value\'s 48"`.